# Inserting content with span in TinyMCE Editor problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I've been trying to insert text with a span tag into the TinyMCE Editor where the cursor is but after pressing ENTER i get everytime the span tag..

This is my function to insert the text with an button:

```
function Insert(){
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<span class="bgTest" data-prefix="ABC">This is a inserted text</span> ');
}
```

This is my browser output: [Imgur](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481)

Comment: you have to cancel the Enter keydown event to prevent the contenteditable from inserting a new "line" and breaking your code. that part's answered aplenty.

Comment: Can you tell me maybe, how to cancel it?

Comment: search for "cancel enter key js" to get the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I'm understanding correctly, the function works fine with your button. But then when you click enter while typing away, it doesn't render properly?

So it sounds like the enter keys default behavior is the problem here. You need to prevent the default behavior of the enter key. You need `preventDefault()`.

I haven't changed your `Insert()` function, so it will still work with your button.

But I've added a `keydown` event listener to the `.tinymce` that will `preventDefault()` the normal behavior of the enter key (which is to add a line break). Then you'll trigger your `Insert()` function.

```
function Insert(){
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<span class="bgTest" data-prefix="ABC">This is a inserted text</span> ');
}

document.querySelector(".tinymce").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Insert();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any more help :).